# How to set builtNumber in Android

Tags: android, versioning

I am uploading a new application on Android Market and it warned me that the new version needs higher `versionCode`. But since I made just a little improvement, I didn't want to assign version 2 from version 1 instead I wanted to say "1.1" but `versionCode` doesn't allow me to type in float numbers.

So I think I can use `versionName` which is the one shown to the users but still I am wondering how to do it in `versionCode` as well.

**Android doc says :**

***android:versionCode*** -

> An internal version number. This number is used only to determine
>   whether one version is more recent
>   than another, with higher numbers
>   indicating more recent versions. This
>   is not the version number shown to
>   users; that number is set by the
>   versionName attribute.
>
> The value must be set as an integer, such as "100". You can define
>   it however you want, as long as each
>   successive version has a higher
>   number. For example, it could be a
>   build number. Or you could translate a
>   version number in "x.y" format to an
>   integer by encoding the "x" and "y"
>   separately in the lower and upper 16
>   bits. Or you could simply increase the
>   number by one each time a new version
>   is released.

But I didn't understand the second paragraph.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that

1. only integers are valid(1, 2, 5689)
2. you can use any integer, for example build number( it is always positive integer )
3. to upload a new version you should use number that is higher then previous

Also, version code isn't seen by anyone, except you, so don't worry. Only version name is exposed, you can set it to any string value(with some length and rational sense restrictions).

Comment: Yeah, but still I was wondering how to do it but I believe there is now way except for `versionName`.